# Trouble with will_paginate method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm trying to paginate with will_paginate in my rails app. I'm following the rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.
In my controller I have

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

In my view I have

```
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

It throws the following error : wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) for will_paginate

Answer (score 14):

Had the same problem.

Change to 3.1.7 (from 3.1.6 in Gemfile) fixed it for me.

Ref. [ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) #589](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/589)

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I browse some time to get the solution, the exact error that I got was :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTptt.png)

**The Solution**

Go to the gemfile and change the `gem 'will_paginate','3.1.6'` to `gem 'will_paginate','3.1.7'`.

then go to the terminal and put `bundle update`

then the will paginate will work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB0ZX.png)

Answer (score 4):

I had just the same issue with different versions.

For my situation, changing from `3.1.8` to the latest version of `3.3.0` solved the problem.

I was using Rails `6.1.1` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

In Gemfile : `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1'`
In other file : `<%= will_paginate @articles%>`